# Convergence of a sequence via bounded sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have for $\{a_k,b_k\}_{k\geq 0}$ with $a_k, b_k \geq 0$ the following condition:

i) $b_k \to 0$.

ii)$
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty (a_k -b_k) < \infty.$

Then is it correct to conclude that $a_k \to 0$: Suppose not. Then there exists a $k'$ such that $a_{k'} \geq \delta>b_{k'}$ which contradicts (ii) since it implies:
$$
\sum_{k = k'}^\infty (a_k -b_k) \geq \sum_{k=k'}^{\infty} (\delta - b_{k'} ) = \infty 
$$

Comment: Not right : from suppose not, you are contradicting the definition of $a_k \to 0$, but that is not just "there exists $k'$ such that $a_{k'} \geq \delta > b_{k'}$". From that point, you seem to use that this above thing is true for all $k \geq k'$, which is also not true. You need to be more careful and proceed from the true definition of the limit not equalling zero. However, the idea of proof by contradiction works out correctly provided you use the right definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct since $a_{k}$ not tending to $0$ only gives $a_k >\delta$ for infinitely many $n$ (for some $\delta >0$).

If $\sum (a_k-b_k)$ converges then $a_k-b_k \to 0$ so $a_k=(a_k-b_k)+b_k \to 0$.